# How to append image to specific grid item using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to append a to the center of a 3x3 grid. Right now the tile is the last grid-item.

The divs are created using an event listener that triggers a function with a for loop.

```
function displayDino(){
for (var i = 0; i < dinoData.length; i++) {
  const dinoDiv = document.createElement('div');
  dinoDiv.className = 'grid-item';
  dinoDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>${dinoData[i]["species"]}<h3><img src="images/${(dinoData[i]["species"].toLowerCase())}.png"><p>${dinoData[i]["fact"]}</p>`;
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(dinoDiv);
}
```

}

I have another function that appends the div I want centered to the grid:

```
function displayHuman(){
  const humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
  humanDiv.className = 'grid-item';
  humanDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>${human.name()}<h3><img src="images/human.png">`;
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(humanDiv);
}
```

How can I generate this grid while making sure a specific div appears at the center of the grid every time?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: if my answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the grayed out checkmark below the downvote button

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is always 3x3 and you want to center the human entry horizontally and vertically, just wait until you are at index 5, add the human, remember that you added him and continue iterating through the array.

```
function displayElements(){
var humanAdded = false;
for (var i = 0; i < dinoData.length; i++) {
  const elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
  elemDiv .className = 'grid-item';
  if(humanAdded == false && i == 5){
    elemDiv .innerHTML = `<h3>${human.name()}<h3><img src="images/human.png">`;
    humanAdded = true;
    i--;
  }else{
    elemDiv .innerHTML = `<h3>${dinoData[i]["species"]}<h3><img src="images/${(dinoData[i]["species"].toLowerCase())}.png"><p>${dinoData[i]["fact"]}</p>`;
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(elemDiv);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts::: If you know where to put your single data in a grid.. just use ***grid-row***, ***grid-column*** css for that *grid-child*... Just ignore the other *grid-childs* and just style that particular *child*... you can have more than one humans which you can put whereever you like this way...

```js
var dinoData = ["Plateosaurus","Abelisaurus","Barsboldia","Litosoraus","Platicore","Manticore","Trynasoraus","Sicocoreus"];
var human = { name: "MEEEEEEEE"};
function displayDino() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dinoData.length; i++) {
    const dinoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    dinoDiv.className = 'grid-item';
    dinoDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>${dinoData[i]}<h3>`;
    document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(dinoDiv);
  }
}

function displayHuman() {
  const humanDiv = document.createElement('div');
  humanDiv.className = 'grid-item human';
  humanDiv.innerHTML = `<h3>${human.name}`;
  document.getElementById('grid').appendChild(humanDiv);
}
displayDino();displayHuman();
```

```css
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.grid-item{
  display: flex;
  padding: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.human{
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">

</div>
```